# Pass spotlight's light to the other side of a mash

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a spotlight in front of a mash:
[image: front view]

And I would like to see the circle of light also from behind the mash. I would also love to have the light a bit diffused like lighting a piece of fabric.

Any tips about how to achieve this?

Thanks alot!

Comment: did you try to make the `Material` of the mash transparent?

Comment: yes but it's not a helping my achieve what i need.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR the effect you're trying to achieve is not possible in the manner you're trying to achieve it *in.*

You've essentially got two or three options here.  And you may want more than one of them.

1. Set the mesh to not cast shadows.  This is pretty much the straight forward solution. It's not going to change the...texture of the light ("make it more diffuse") but it will mean that the light will illuminate other objects behind it.
2. Use two lights.  One light will illuminate the mesh and *only the mesh.* You'll have to use physics layers for this, and layer masks.  The second light--which is more diffuse than the first--illuminates everything *but* the mesh.

   - Along with #1 and #2, there's a thing called a [cookie](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Light-cookie.html) that might come in handy.
3. There might be a solution involving custom shaders. Not having explored this in the past myself, I can only say "it is a research direction I thought of." Research it. (Note: Shaders are complicated and Hard).
4. Writing your own lighting solution. This is probably *the* most advanced topic I can suggest.  By which I mean "this will solve your problem, but keep in mind, there's about 40 years of research already been done to come up with the models we have which don't solve your problem."  We only started to get subsurface scattering as an option in the last three to five.  Now you want subsurface scattering to *affect the light cone for other objects.* Sooo...have fun with that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 1 and 2 are good ideas but don't help with the main issue of displaying the light on the other side of the mash. I guess ill have to write my own shader. thanks!